# Type on image vs. type on standard background

Tags: image, image-format, type

Does anyone have any research or a/b testing regarding whether people are more likely to read and retain information when type is on an image as opposed to a standard background? I'd imagine that people tend to skip over type on images because of the visual distraction, but I'd like to have some data to back up that assumption.

Comment: What do you mean by *image* and what do you mean by *background*? An image can have far less visual details than a noisy background. And what do you mean by *standard background*?

Comment: By "type is on" do you mean "text is over"?